# srand in Raku, is it expected?

Tags: github-actions, raku, rakudo

I am trying to run a code containing `srand` function:

```
srand(1);
my @x = (1..1000).roll(100);
my @y = (200..7000).roll(100);
say sum(@x);
say sum(@y);
say $*KERNEL
```

From the docs its pretty clear that `srand` is [**platform** dependent](https://docs.raku.org/routine/srand#(Num)_sub_srand).
When I test this in my Windows 10, I get

```
46221
375477
win32
```

When I test it in glot.io [here](https://glot.io/snippets/g89shj8noe), I get

```
50941
405340
linux
```

in tio.run [here](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/7@4KDEvRcNQ05ort1LBoULBVkHDUE/P0MDAQFOvKD8nRwPIhEpWgiSNDAz09MzRpYsTKxWKS3M1HCqQOZVQjoqWt2uQn6vP//8A), I get

```
47784
354115
linux (5.2.11.100.fc.29.x.86._.64)
```

in repl.it, I get
[image]

```
51496
362664
linux
```

in raku irc channel, its

[image]

```
50941
405340
linux
```

So even when the platform is `linux` i.e `$*KERNEL ~~ 'linux'`, there are myriads of output. Is this expected ?

Why I am asking this here is because I cannot test the following code in continuous integration (e.g. github actions) due to this variability even in `linux`. The following code *fails* in GitHub Actions:

```
use Test;
if $*KERNEL ~~ 'win32' {
    srand(1); # From Raku docs: Note that srand is called with a platform dependent value when a Raku program is started.
    # This is tested on my own Windows 10
    my @x = (1..1000).roll(100);
    my @y = (200..7000).roll(100);
    is sum(@x), 46221;
    is sum(@y), 375477;
}
elsif $*KERNEL ~~ 'linux' {
    srand(1); # From Raku docs: Note that srand is called with a platform dependent value when a Raku program is started.
    my @x = (1..1000).roll(100);
    my @y = (200..7000).roll(100);
    is sum(@x), 50941;
    is sum(@y), 405340;

}
else {
    skip "Not tested on Mac !", 1;
}
```

I want to make this test work while doing continuous integration.

Comment: I think the only thing setting `srand` guarantees you, is a repeatable random sequence on that particular combination of hardware / OS / software.  That's it.

Comment: I was actually looking for something like `set.seed` in R or `random.seed` in Python which generate OS **independent** stable values. I thought `srand` would give me at least OS **dependent** stable values, which was not the case. Its fine, I will look for Raku modules now, which serves my need better.

Comment: @SumanKhanal from the documentation I understand that should be the case. Let me check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only thing setting `srand` guarantees you, is a repeatable random sequence on that particular combination of hardware / OS / software. That's it.

Perhaps a Raku module can serve your need better.

Answer (score 6):

Well, srand is a [low-level nqp operator](https://github.com/Raku/nqp/blob/e01f299b4a76193c3405d6840a154dffe70b7695/docs/ops.markdown). It's tested against calls to [`nqp::rand_n`](https://github.com/Raku/nqp/blob/609d071659a3fe762d738f595ab3b7e804e0805c/t/nqp/059-nqpop.t) So if you do *exactly the same* number of calls you're bound to get the same result. I'm afraid that `roll` involves *a random* number of calls so you will not have the same result even if you do it in the same platform:

[image: Rolling with srand]

Testing the sequences obtained is, if I may, not a good strategy for testing randomness. There are many possible strategies for doing it, some of them are featured here [TDD for a random algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161133/tdd-for-a-random-algorithm) In general, you should check for what random feature you want out of it: if you want a (rough) uniform distribution, you should check for that, or if you want anything else, ditto. In this case it's likely that what you want is to have a gaussian distribution of sums, maybe the easiest thing would be to check that the histogram follows roughly a bell curve.